# How replace all attribute completely in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, attributes, attr

How could to replace  all `required="required"` with `data-test="done"` in jQuery?

```
<div id="commentform">
<div>
<label>Comment:</label>
<textarea required="required"></textarea>
</div>
<p>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" required="required">
</p>
<p>
<label>Mobile:</label>
<input type="text">
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Research the `removeAttr()` and `attr()` jQuery methods. That being said, `test` is not a valid attribute for an `input` element and should be avoided. Use a `data` attribute if you want to store custom metadata in an element.

Comment: Just FYI it would be `data-test`, but at least you've shown that the HTML can be amended. Can you please also edit the question to show what you've tried, as SO is not a free code service.

Comment: still wrong. correct would be data-test="done". You can access that attrribut with $('#someid').data('test');

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's just for a test, I want to learn how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Then my first comment has your answer on the methods you need to use.